# PackageParserException: Package ...base.apk has no certificates at entry AndroidManifest.xml

Tags: android, exception, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, signing

I'm running my app in debug mode and it's ok. But when I sign it and try to install apk, this error happens in Logcat, and phone shows "App is not installed".

This is the same on every phone with <7.0 android, so I thought the problem is in app signature, but I've tried **both V1, V2, only V1** - seems like android studio doesn't even recognise that I changed something.

Tried to disable V2 completely with this, but no luck.

```
signingConfigs{
    release {
        storeFile file("keystore.jks")
        storePassword 'password'
        keyAlias 'alias'
        keyPassword 'password'
        v2SigningEnabled false
    }
}
```

What else can I do?

```
C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\jre\bin>java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_152-release"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1248-b01)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.152-b01, mixed mode)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Today I've updated Android Studio to 3.3 and encountered the same issue.

I fixed it after delete Build folder, **Clean Project**, **Invalidate Caches/Restart**.
And after that I could generate signed application via **Build -> Generate Signed Bundle/APK** with only V1 signature.

Build signed application with *signingConfigs release* still doesn't work.

You can try my solution.

Comment: Ironically I was just writing my own answer for that, but thanks for helping me. I also think newest update broke something.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I solved it by making those actions, **but I don't sure what actually fixed it.** Anyway :

1. copy all the code into another project (weird?)
2. create another keystore
3. remove all functions that require [newest java features](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support) and therefore newest Android
4. after that, only choose v1 jar signature

Comment: Which Java features were required?

Answer (score 0):

Steps to generate signed apk:

1. Build release unsigned apk.
2. zipalign the unsigned APK using the command prompt.

   ```
   zipalign -v -p 4 my-app-unsigned.apk my-app-unsigned-aligned.apk
   ```
3. Signed the APK with Sonim private key using app signer via command prompt.

   ```
   apksigner sign --ks my-release-key.jks --out my-app-release.apk my-app-unsigned-aligned.apk
   ```
4. Install the apk in device.